# CoreMediaIO, incorrectly updated properties kCMIODevicePropertyDeviceIsRunningSomewhere

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, avfoundation, isight

I need to receive an event when some process starts using the camera. I did this through CMIOObjectGetPropertyData. 
But it does not work correctly, the correct value is only the first time it is accessed.

I also tried to use the CMIOObjectAddPropertyListenerBlock but he did not work it from me. Tell me please, what am I doing wrong? I will be very grateful.

```
while (1)
{
    UInt32 value = 0;
    UInt32 valuePropertySize = sizeof(flag);
    CMIOObjectPropertyAddress opa = {kCMIODevicePropertyDeviceIsRunningSomewhere,
        kAudioObjectPropertyScopeWildcard, kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster};

    OSStatus result = CMIOObjectGetPropertyData(device, &opa, 0, NULL, sizeof(UInt32), &valuePropertySize, &value);
    NSLog(@"%d : %d", result, value);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. Getting data with `CMIOObjectGetPropertyData` worked but registering a listener block with `CMIOObjectAddPropertyListenerBlock` never received any event.

The solution to the issue was totally unrelated to the CMIO* code.
Basically, I forgot to start the run loop, and that prevented receiving events.

Please take a look here: [currentRunLoop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrunloop/1412291-currentrunloop?language=objc)

Adding a simple `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];` fixed the issue for me