# How to detect microphone is in use macOS

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-audio, microphone, iokit

I would like to know if there any way to detect if microphone is in use on macos system.

I would like to achieve that programatically. Code snippet or some references to start on would be appreciated

I have read about CoreAudio, would that API be enough or should I go deeper and start with IOKit?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect microphone usage on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574616/how-to-detect-microphone-usage-on-os-x)