# Incorrect Value Returned by kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceIsRunningSomewhere for External Devices like AirPods

Tags: c++, swift, objective-c, macos, core-audio

I'm experiencing an issue where `kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceIsRunningSomewhere` is not returning the expected values for wireless audio devices such as AirPods. The expected behavior is to return 1 when the device is in use and 0 when it is not. However, even when the device is actively being used, it consistently returns 0.

This problem seems to be a common one, as evidenced by discussions on platforms like the Apple Developer Forums and Stack Overflow.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/741026

[How to detect microphone usage on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574616/how-to-detect-microphone-usage-on-os-x)

I have attempted various methods to retrieve the correct value of `kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceIsRunningSomewhere` for wireless devices but have not been successful. One peculiar observation is that when I use `ListenerBlock` on `kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceIsRunningSomewhere`, the `ListenerBlock` is triggered, which is strange given that the property always reports the device as inactive, meaning "0".

Can anyone provide insights or solutions on how to accurately obtain the `kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceIsRunningSomewhere` value for wireless audio devices?

Comment: This might be a good question for DTS

Comment: @sbooth May I ask what DTS stands for and how it is related to the issue? Thank you!

Comment: DTS is Apple Developer Technical Support. https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

Comment: Thank you for help. I should submit a ticket to DTS.